# defMacro and useMacro usage on QuickBooks QBXML

Tags: quickbooks

I'm figuring out how to use the defMacro and useMacro on qbxml. As I have read on https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/Common/newOSR/index.html ; I can use the defMacro attribute to assign a name to the TxnID, then use the assigned name to reference that transaction by using useMacro in another transaction.

I tried to do this on BillAdd and BillPaymentCheckAdd request

the BillAdd request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?qbxml version="7.0"?>
<QBXML>
   <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="continueOnError">
      <BillAddRq requestID="0">
         <BillAdd defMacro="TxnID:1258">
            <VendorRef>
               <FullName>Sample</FullName>
            </VendorRef>
            <TxnDate>2012-12-22</TxnDate>
            <DueDate>2013-01-21</DueDate>
            <RefNumber>1258</RefNumber>
            <TermsRef>
               <FullName>Net 30</FullName>
            </TermsRef>
            <ExpenseLineAdd>
               <AccountRef>
                  <FullName>Crop Sales</FullName>
               </AccountRef>
               <Amount>400.00</Amount>
            </ExpenseLineAdd>
            <ExpenseLineAdd>
               <AccountRef>
                  <FullName>Utilities</FullName>
               </AccountRef>
               <Amount>1000.00</Amount>
            </ExpenseLineAdd>
         </BillAdd>
      </BillAddRq>
   </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

this data is received by QuickBooks just fine,
and sends this as a response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<QBXML>
   <QBXMLMsgsRs>
      <BillAddRs requestID="0" statusCode="0" statusSeverity="Info" statusMessage="Status OK">
         <BillRet>
            <TxnID>371-1459505632</TxnID>
            <TimeCreated>2016-04-01T18:13:52+08:00</TimeCreated>
            <TimeModified>2016-04-01T18:13:52+08:00</TimeModified>
            <EditSequence>1459505632</EditSequence>
            <TxnNumber>218</TxnNumber>
            <VendorRef>
               <ListID>80000001-1448596175</ListID>
               <FullName>Sample</FullName>
            </VendorRef>
            <APAccountRef>
               <ListID>80000031-1458630264</ListID>
               <FullName>Accounts Payable</FullName>
            </APAccountRef>
            <TxnDate>2012-12-22</TxnDate>
            <DueDate>2013-01-21</DueDate>
            <AmountDue>1400.00</AmountDue>
            <RefNumber>1258</RefNumber>
            <TermsRef>
               <ListID>80000006-1448593319</ListID>
               <FullName>Net 30</FullName>
            </TermsRef>
            <IsPaid>false</IsPaid>
            <ExpenseLineRet>
               <TxnLineID>373-1459505632</TxnLineID>
               <AccountRef>
                  <ListID>8000000A-1448593319</ListID>
                  <FullName>Crop Sales</FullName>
               </AccountRef>
               <Amount>400.00</Amount>
            </ExpenseLineRet>
            <ExpenseLineRet>
               <TxnLineID>374-1459505632</TxnLineID>
               <AccountRef>
                  <ListID>8000001E-1448593319</ListID>
                  <FullName>Utilities</FullName>
               </AccountRef>
               <Amount>1000.00</Amount>
            </ExpenseLineRet>
         </BillRet>
      </BillAddRs>
   </QBXMLMsgsRs>
</QBXML>
```

then I send the Bill Payment request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?qbxml version="7.0"?>
<QBXML>
   <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="continueOnError">
      <BillPaymentCheckAddRq requestID="2">
         <BillPaymentCheckAdd>
            <PayeeEntityRef>
               <FullName>Sample</FullName>
            </PayeeEntityRef>
            <APAccountRef>
               <FullName>Accounts Payable</FullName>
            </APAccountRef>
            <TxnDate>2016-03-16</TxnDate>
            <BankAccountRef>
               <FullName>Sample Bank</FullName>
            </BankAccountRef>
            <RefNumber>3500</RefNumber>
            <Memo>Sample Memo</Memo>
            <AppliedToTxnAdd>
               <TxnID useMacro="TxnID:1258">1258</TxnID>
               <PaymentAmount>100.00</PaymentAmount>
            </AppliedToTxnAdd>
         </BillPaymentCheckAdd>
      </BillPaymentCheckAddRq>
   </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

QuickBooks replies with an error `The given object ID "1258" in the field "transaction id" is invalid.`

I tried removing TxnID on the useMacro attribute so i end up with `<TxnID useMacro="1258">1258</TxnID>` the but i still get the same error

I also tried removing the text inside the TxnID node and it becomes `<TxnID useMacro="1258"></TxnID>` but then i get `"There is a missing element: "TxnID"."`

the site notes that "defMacro was introduced with SDK 2.0, so it only works with 2.0 and higher requests." so I suspect that i might have a version problem, but searching for which QuickbooksWebConnector version supports that, i got nothing.

I have no idea what is wrong, I'm using QuickbooksWebConnector 2.1.0.30 and QuickBooks Premier - Accountant Edition 2014.

Any information would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macros only work *within a given qbXML request*. They *do not* work across requests.

e.g. Something like this will work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?qbxml version="7.0"?>
<QBXML>
   <QBXMLMsgsRq>
      <CustomerAddRq>
         ... define your macro in here ...
      </CustomerAddRq>
      <InvoiceAddRq>
         ... use your macro in here ...
      </InvoiceAddRq>
   </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

But if you broke that up into two requests it *would not work*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?qbxml version="7.0"?>
<QBXML>
   <QBXMLMsgsRq>
      <CustomerAddRq>
         ... define your macro in here ...
      </CustomerAddRq>
   </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

and:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?qbxml version="7.0"?>
<QBXML>
   <QBXMLMsgsRq>
      <InvoiceAddRq>
         ... use your macro in here ...
      </InvoiceAddRq>
   </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

Also, regarding this:

> the site notes that "defMacro was introduced with SDK 2.0, so it only works with 2.0 and higher requests."

You are using SDK version:

```
<?qbxml version="7.0"?>
```